# Visual Studio highlight for JSX/TSX (as in VS Code)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jsx, tsx

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2022 and previously was working with VS Code. Is there any chance to have the same highlight options for JSX/TSX files like it is in VS Code? In Visual Studio I just see white and blue colors. Plus orange for strings and only if it is not in JSX/TSX code...

Difference:

[image: VS Code colors]

and

[image: Visual Studio Colors]